# Accessing Content sent via stream header context

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Using the following:

```
$auth = array(
    'iAmWhiteListed' => 'me',
    'otherStuff'     => 'mystuff'
);

$sendAuth = array(
    'http' => array(
            'method'    => 'POST',
            'content'   => json_encode( $auth ),
            'header'    => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" . "Accept: application/json\r\n"
            )
); 

$authContext    = stream_context_create( $sendAuth );
$authResult     = file_get_contents( $url, false, $authContext );
```

How does a PHP script access the data send in the `content` of the `http` request? (In this case to verify the data therein and send back an appropriate response?)

Comment: Using normal $_POST, you've specified the method in the `http` array. Have you tried `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @Styphon The `$_POST` array is detected, but prints and dumps as being empty.

Comment: Rather than using `json_encode($auth)` you should be using `http_build_query($auth)`. See if that helps.

Comment: @Styphon Nope, still there, still empty. I'm using a WAMP environment, would that affect it (still using full `http://` url)? I am receiving the actual header meta info no problem.

Comment: I've not heard of WAMP affecting it before, but then I've never tried it with WAMP before. That should be working as far as I'm aware, that was the only thing I could see wrong, good luck with this.

Comment: Glad you managed to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

When using `Content-Type: application/json`, the $_POST array is not populated. To fill it, I had to grab the input using `php://input` and decode it back into array format.

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($data, true);
```